# Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, ubuntu, memory-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096582/allowed-memory-size-of-x-bytes-exhausted)

I'm handling with a quite little big database (87mb) import and to do that I use a php script.
All the operations are made in locale with an apache installation on Ubuntu Lucid.

When I run the script after few minutes I receive this error:

```
Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted
```

I've changed `memory_limit` to 2GB in php.ini file and restarted apache. After that I've checked `phpinfo()` and I see that `memory_limit` is set to '2048M' so all is ok.

But when i relaunch my script i receive the same error, 256mb memory limit exahusted.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: show us some code. we need to know what's going on in the script.

Comment: The script is the wordpress importer and the database file is a WML file (Wordpress Export File)

Comment: You change the memory_limit to be 1GB, but `phpinfo()` shows 2GB, and *so all is ok* ??

Comment: Sorry, it was a type. I've changed the 'memory_limit' to 2048M, not 1GB

Comment: What location for the `php.ini` file does `phpinfo()` show? Did you modify that file, or another one?

Answer (score 14):

If the script you are using is borrowed from someone else make sure there is no `ini_set('memory_limit', '256M')` which would produce the exactly effect you are seeing in spite of any change you made in php.ini.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu has two php.ini's, one for apache and one for cli.
Are you sure you edited the right one?
The one for command line is usually in `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`.

Comment: There are also a '/etc/php5/cli/php.ini' and memory_limit was set to '-1'.

Comment: Anyway I run the script through a web browser, not command line

Answer (score 0):

Most probably wrong php.ini is used.

In the same `phpinfo()`-s output you can check what file is used exactly, search for "Configuration File".

You can call the `phpinfo()` function from your real script used, to be sure to get the settings for exactly your script (different settings can be used for different virtual hsots, paths, etc).

Comment: I've added phpinfo() to the header of the script and it show me the same thing... memory_limit is set to 2048M but i receive the error message. I can't figure why this could be happening...