# DomPDF > Allowed memory exhausted

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, dompdf, php-5.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096582/allowed-memory-size-of-x-bytes-exhausted)

I'm hitting a very tricky issue.

1. As per phpInfo, the memory limit set for this script is 256M. However, domPDF gets only 64M
2. When I run the PDF creation action from the frontend, it works like a charm. When a cron calls a sfTask to do it, I get this:

> [28-Sep-2012 10:41:03] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of
>   67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 76 bytes) in
>   /home3/myspace/public_html/prasad/myapp/lib/vendor/dompdf/include/frame_decorator.cls.php
>   on line 30

And for the record, its printing one simple page whose PDF size is < 5K

Can someone help?

Comment: I am using DOMPDF 0.6.0 beta 3

Comment: I guess the settings for PHP-CLI are different from PHP-CGI/mod_php. You could try to find out using the command `php -i | grep memory_limit` (put it in a shell-script and let the script run by cron if you don't have shell access).

Comment: Ok, I will try that. Another error I get is: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 83 bytes) in /home3/myspace/public_html/prasad/myapp/lib/vendor/dompdf/include/style.cls.php on line 720
/bin/sh: line 1:  6511 Segmentation fault      /ramdisk/bin/php5 /home3/myspace/public_html/prasad/myapp/symfony job:cron --job-type="job" What does **/bin/sh: line 1:  6511 Segmentation fault** mean?

Comment: the output is 64M. Is that not sufficient? How can I raise that limit?

Comment: No, 64M is not sufficient hence the "Allowed memory"-error. You have to find the php.ini of the CLI and change it there. The alternative is to change the setting via command line - like `php -d memory_limit=256M /path/to/your/php-file`. A [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) occurs when a program tries to access invalid memory. It's likely a problem with the PHP-interpreter itself. It would be hard to find the reason, even with shell-access.

Comment: Are you using more tables?. If yes, Try to reduce the tables and nested tables. Usage of more tables may causes memory exhausted error.

Comment: No **Hearaman**, there is just 1 table. **Vstm**, you have no clue how grateful I am to you. Pl post both the responses as a answer. Calling with the mem-limit parameter executed the script. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make from vstms comment an awnser because Prasad solved his problem:

> No, 64M is not sufficient hence the "Allowed memory"-error. You have
>   to find the php.ini of the CLI and change it there. The alternative is
>   to change the setting via command line - like php -d memory_limit=256M
>   /path/to/your/php-file. A segmentation fault occurs when a program
>   tries to access invalid memory. It's likely a problem with the
>   PHP-interpreter itself. It would be hard to find the reason, even with
>   shell-access.