# How can I get a multiple page pdf output from php file?

Tags: php, pdf

I used the following code but getting the error as "fatal error allowed memory size of bytes exhausted (tried to allocate bytes)".

```
include 'mpdf60/mpdf.php';
ob_clean(); 
$abc=new mPDF();
$temp=//some html code
$final=$temp;//.
$abc->WriteHTML($final);
$abc->Output();
exit();
```

My output having bunch of records. its not getting all the records on the pdf. How can I do it?

Comment: [How can I get a multiple page pdf output from php file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096582/allowed-memory-size-of-x-bytes-exhausted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message : fatal error allowed memory size of bytes exhausted

is telling you to increase the memory you can do it directly in your script

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Comment: You are right, is better to put the right value for example if it needs 512 MB of ram you should put : ini_set('memory_limit', '512M'); the -1 will use what it needs to. Its easier when you are testing and developping.