# Allowed memory size exhausted while rotate image - how to catch exception like that?

Tags: php, rotation

I have got  the following error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
 34820 bytes) in rotate.php
```

I did not mange to reproduce it , How can I prevent such things and how can I catch that and return false instead of crash the process.

I can say that I added logger to my code maybe is it related to that error?.

php ini configuration:

```
memory_limit = 128M
```

rotation code:

```
$this->logger->info();
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $rotate_angle, 0);
imagejpeg($rotate,$img);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096582/allowed-memory-size-of-x-bytes-exhausted)

Comment: How big is the image you're trying to rotate; what angle are you rotating by?