# PHP Memory limit not taking effect in normal php scripts

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've assigned the memory limit of php to 999m so it appears in phpinfo like

> memory_limit   999M    999M

when I use phpinfo(); to show it.

Unfortunately when I try to run a fairly large script, it seems like the limit is 256M

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 40 bytes) in /xxx/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1403

Anyone have any ideas why or what I can do to increase the limit (and have it actually work)

If it helps I'm running centos5 32bit and with php running in fcgi mode

Comment: You edited the correct `php.ini`? (See `phpinfo()`, or `php -i` (note, that the different sapis (apache-module, `cgi`, `cli`, ...) use different `php.inis`)) You restarted your server? You ever thought about, why your scripts requires sooo much memory?!

Comment: `memory_limit 999M 999M` - surely you meant `memory_limit 999M`

Comment: isn't your WordPress installation setting its own memory limit via `ini_set('memory_limit', ...)` ?

Comment: how about optimising the script, you shouldn't need that much memory.

Comment: Yeah I did edit the correct php.ini, it shows fine in phpinfo

Comment: @d_inevitable Yeah that was the output from phpinfo in php.ini its set to memory_limit 999M

Comment: @Dagon That's not an option, its wordpress, I can't optimize it since I have truckload of post metas used.

Comment: that's just a poor excuse for writing bad code.

Comment: I don't know what version of php your using, but prior to PHP 5.2.1, in order to use this directive it had to be enabled at compile time by using --enable-memory-limit in the configure line. (From the php manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)

Comment: Is this VPS or shared host? If so perhaps that is the physical limit or the upper limit set by your provider?

Comment: I did not see if you were running php-fpm.  But if you are/were then you should check your fpm pool to see if it is set there.  I ran into this where the pool file had 
`php_admin_value[memory_limit]=32M`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a php file called test.php, put inside:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Check for "**Configuration File (php.ini) Path**" and "**Loaded Configuration File**" to see the correct php.ini path.
Edit **php.ini** and search for **memory_limit** and set it to:

```
memory_limit = 999M
```

Check if you have more than one occurrency of memory_limit into the php.ini file. In the case, delete it.

Stop apache, and then restart it (apachectl restart | apachectl graceful | kill -1 are not ok. Stop, then start).

Recheck test.php to see if the new parameter got acquired.

Comment: The parameter is acquired, just doesn't work in wordpress, there isn't any overrides, did a grep with for ini_set and nada

Comment: @DarrellDing you should grep php_value if you want to see if it's set in apache somewhere as well.

Comment: My wordpress version (3.1.2) defines a file called wp-includes/default-constants.php that create a constant called WP_MEMORY_LIMIT. You can ovveride its value into wp-settings.php. Wordpress overwrite the php memory limit value setted into php.ini if it's smaller than the value you define with WP_MEMORY_LIMIT.

Comment: Fixed, it wasn't WP_MEMORY_LIMIT, apparently wordpress uses WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT as their admin max limit.

Comment: Was the closest I got to an answer

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar issue,  for me it was an extra ini file that was loaded called "99-liip-developer.ini". At the top of the file the memory_limit was defined at 265M, which overwrote the memory_limit defined in php.ini.

Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: Found a file called www.conf in /etc/nginx/fpm/pool.d. I would have never even thought to look there.

Comment: Maybe also look for /usr/local/lib/php.ini or /usr/local/php/lib/php.ini

Comment: THANK YOU! This also drove me crazy :D

Comment: In phpinfo() output there is "Additional .ini files parsed" key.

Answer (score 5):

Type `php --ini` to find the configuration paths.

Change `memory_limit` to whatever value you need.
Make sure that you are changing it on both these files: `php.ini` and `conf.d/php-memory-limits.ini`

(in my case, I use -1 to have unlimited memory (*of course, not unlimited but as much as my computer can handle*))

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you set this on the top of your script:

```
 ini_set("memory_limit","512M");
```

in the script that is consuming so much of your memory instead of allowing all scripts to consume so much memory. You can also put this in the .htaccess of your /wp-includes/

```
 php_value memory_limit 512M
```

More information and explanation here:
http://www.mydigitallife.info/php-allowed-memory-size-exchausted-fatal-error/

Comment: Its already been set under /etc/php.ini so the limit is high enough, just wondering why it doesn't take effect in the script but the limit is shown under a phpinfo

Comment: Because it can be overruled by wordpress in the wp-config.php file.

Comment: By using `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');` in that file for example.

Comment: Its not, already has both ini_set('memory_limit', '999M');
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '999M');
defined inside wp-config.php

Comment: Well, it's very simple, there is still a limit somewhere. This could be set by your webhost, in some file, .htaccess etc. I suggest you try using all options to override the memory_limit without asking why it won't work as you want it or should be. Also look at the same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903363/allowed-memory-size-of-268435456-bytes-exhausted maybe it could be of some use :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting this at the top of your file

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '999M')
```

How much system memory do you have available? Did you restart Apache after editing your php.ini file (I assume you have php installed as a module)?

Try:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Comment: I've already tried that it still maxes out at 256 for some vague reason

Comment: Did you restart apache? The code in your php.ini was invalid, too... Are you sure you don't have a second setting in your php.ini that is overwriting your custom line? Check for that, too...

Comment: it shows memory limit 999m in phpinfo so that isn't the issue right now, I'm just wondering how come it doesn't work in wordpress.  Wordpress's wp-config has been set to use up to 999 as well

Comment: Did... you... restart... apache?

Comment: Who manages your server? How much memory is currently available if you  run "free -m" via the command line?

Comment: total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2025       1925         99          0         25       1381
-/+ buffers/cache:        518       1506
Swap:         4094        369       3725

Comment: well, time to reinstall php lol... Seriously, though, this is quite odd. Try restarting apache again and see if it takes hold. Very very weird...

Answer (score 0):

Unsure, but this came up in the google search for me:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-cbnet-ping-optimizer-lots-of-errors-on-ping-optimizer-_help-please

The ping optimizer was cramming a table full on the DB and clearing solved the problem. The error was almost the same:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 80 bytes) in
>   /home/user1/public_html/domain/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1400

So see if a plugin is doing the same, then clear it and log it on WP somewhere so it can be fixed if that is the problem.

Comment: My problem is that I'm unable to increase the memory limit no matter what I do, not so much that I'm having an error

Comment: @DarrellDing are you using any plugins like Memory Bump? You might want to check the setting there as well. Look all the way down the line: php.ini (and local php.ini if there are multiple), .htaccess, and search the php files for changes as well. Check with a small script to the side (just a quick script not in wordpress) to see if the php.ini and/or .htaccess files set it properly using `ini_get('memory_limit')` to check it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you server/virtual server in apache is not configured to overwrite PHP configuration. Even if you use:

```
php_value memory_limit 512M
```

Your server may have something like:

```
php_value memory_limit 32M
```

which will make your changes in php.ini useless.
To fix this:

- Either edit the php_value value in your server configuration.
- Or remove it from your web server, so it uses PHP global settings.